# Use math equation as bchart label

Tags: equations, bar-chart

I used bchart to generate a chart, it worked well in almost case, however I have to put a math equation into bar label but it is unable to compile.

My document worked well

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{bchart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bchart}[max=0.3]
        \bcbar[label=$\theta$]{0.2}
    \end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

Now I have to change the label to `$\theta=a^2$`, how can I put the equation into the label value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enclose in a group, i.e. `{ }`, the text:

```
\bcbar[label={$\theta=a^2$}]{0.2}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{bchart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{bchart}[max=0.3]
        \bcbar[label={$\theta=a^2$}]{0.2}
    \end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @KhoiNguyen Thanks are better conveyed by accepting (clicking the green tick mark) and upvoting the answer :-)