# How to put a label on a wire using CircuiTikz

Tags: labels, circuitikz

I would like to put a label on a short circuit element.

I have tried something like this:

```
     \draw
     (2,2) to [short=$L = \lambda/4$, *-*] (5.5,2)
     (2,0) to [short, *-*] (5.5,0);
```

but nothing happens.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you need to protect that `=` from the PGFkeys parser, see: [How can I put `=` in a TikZ node label specified as an option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61471) and [Equal `=` sign within TikZ label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110485)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the notation `l={<label>}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw
     (2,2) to [short,l=${L = \lambda/4}$, *-*] (5.5,2)
     (2,0) to [short, *-*] (5.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The reason behind which the label needs to be grouped in this case can be found in [Use math equation as bchart label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142937/use-math-equation-as-bchart-label/142939#142939).